# How do I fix the gap in my site's footer tag when viewed on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

When viewed on any iOS 9 browser (Safari, Chrome, or Firefox) on an iPhone 6S, the `footer` element on the bottom of my site has a gap. It's behaving almost as if the content *inside* the footer is not setting its height, but rather the footer's height is only being set by its `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values. I have not observed this behavior on any other browser/OS configuration, including earlier versions of iOS.

Any idea on how I can eliminate this effect and make my `footer` flush with the bottom of the page, and without its contents overflowing?

Here's a screenshot from my BrowserStack session

[image: iOS 9 footer height bug on BrowserStack]

---

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/mwqtdoxv/)

I'll have the page up on https://stamminator.github.io/ temporarily if you want to easily test it on an iPhone, as well.

### HTML

```
<body>
<form class="page-wrapper">
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class=navbar-brand>Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="liHome"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown" id="liService">
            <a href="/" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
              Service <i style="font-size:x-small; opacity:0.4;" class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
              <li><a href="/">Create Ticket</a></li>
              <li><a href="/>">View Tickets</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="liProposals">
            <a href="/">Proposals</a>
          </li>
          <li id="liProjects">
            <a href="/">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li id="liDocuments">
            <a href="/">Documents</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="body-content">
    <div id="subheader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-10 padding-right-none-sm" style="text-align: right;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnLogout" style="margin-bottom: 15px;"><strong>Sign out</strong></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-2 padding-left-none-sm">
          <div class="button-group">
            <select id="ddlLocations" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <option selected="selected" value="0">(select option)</option>
              <option value="7889">Option 1</option>
              <option value="8736">Option 2</option>
              <option value="10398">Option 3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="aspnet-placeholder-content" class="container">
      <!--This is where page-specific server-generated content from ASP.NET will render-->
      <h3>Page Title</h3>
      <br />
      <p>
        Page content
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center footer-content">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h5>Footer text</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h5>Copyright stuff</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</form>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

form.page-wrapper {
  padding: 51px 0 0;
  position: static;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section#body-content {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section#body-content #subheader {
  background: #7e5bbd;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#aspnet-placeholder-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  background: url("https://s25.postimg.org/4ylsw3w0v/brushed-metal-horizontal-darker-450.jpg") center top;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  footer .footer-content div:first-child {
    text-align: right;
    border-right: 1px solid #868686;
  }
  footer .footer-content div:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #868686;
  }
}

footer h5 {
  color: #868686;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .padding-left-none-sm,
  .padding-right-none-sm {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .padding-left-none-sm {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .padding-right-none-sm {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .text-right-sm {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .text-left-sm {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't test it, but check if you can fix it by changing 'height: 100%' to 'min-height: 100%' on form.page-wrapper styles

Comment: Are you using a css reset?

Comment: That gap appears to be the _footer background_ no cover the complete footer